# Maven WebApp with Intellij - procedure

Tags: java, maven, servlets, intellij-idea

What is the procedure to make a Java EE WebApp with Maven and Intellij?

This is what I do:

- File / New / Project
- Project Type : Maven
- Create From archetype : maven-archetype-webapp

But when I create a servlet IntelliJ shows a symbol on the servlet:
[image]

This symbol is "Java class located out of the source root. Refer to the section Configuring Content Roots for details"

If I launch the project I get an error.

If I mark the "resources" directory as "Sources Root", the project works.

But if I reload Maven (right click / maven / reimport) the resources directory lost the "Source Root" structure.

I think something is wrong in my procedure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a new folder under **main** called **java**. Then right-click it and select **Mark Directory As** -> **Sources Root**. Use this directory for all your java code and everything should work!

Comment: Your answer works but ... if i right click on java folder i dont have the context menu for create servlet (must create class and then extend httpservlet)

I think there is a method in Intellij .... but i dont know :(

Comment: Could you please specify which menu do you mean? Does it show up when you click on resources folder?

Comment: If i right click on "resources" folder i can select New / Servlet.

But if i right click on "java" folder i dont have "Servlet"

Comment: chrkv - I tried to do what you said above. But I am not getting an option Sourcess Root under Mark Directory As. Could you please let me know if I need to install any plugins for this?

Comment: @VenkataRamireddyCH it should be there. Could you please specify which options do you see there?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to Chrkv !

1). Create a new folder under main called java. Then right-click it and select Mark Directory As -> Sources Root

2). In Project Structure / Modules / Web enable the checkbox for makes java "Sources Root"

[image]

Now i can use right click on java / New / Servlet.

What is the "resources" directory ? (if i cant create servlet here)

Is this the right precedure ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also encountered the same issue and found a solution by replacing the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

by following dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

after adding this and making the java the source root directory as mentioned in above answer, the intellij idea provided the option for creating filters along with web services. I followed the steps from the link : http://www.tugay.biz/2013/10/hello-world-web-application-with-maven.html

Comment: The steps mentioned by magikbibi is the correct way by using javax.servlet dependency since changing the dependency is not that good. It worked for me as well